# Pandas Series.replace replaces the entire series even in an iterative loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this dataframe and I wanna replace some of its rows with another value based on a condition.

```
df = pd.Dataframe({'col1':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3]})
for rows in df['col1']:
    if rows == "1":
        df['col1'].replace({rows: "A"}, inplace=True)
    else:
        df['col1'].replace({rows: "BC"}, inplace=True)
```

However, the results are weird:

```
>>> print(df)
    col1
0    BC
1    BC
2    BC
3    BC
4    BC
5    BC
6    BC
7    BC
8    BC
9    BC
10   BC
11   BC
12   BC
13   BC
14   BC
15   BC
16   BC
17   BC
18   BC
```

Am I missing something here or am I misunderstanding how series.replace works?
I'm thinking this has got to be some form of logic error.

Comment: df['col1'].replace you are replacing the whole dataframe

Comment: Please use: `df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(df['col1'] == '1', 'A')` in replacement of your entire loop.

Comment: avoid for loops if you can. @DavidErickson's solution is one way; you can also use `numpy.where` : ``df.assign(col1=np.where(df.col1 == 1, "A", "BC"))``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in each cycle of the loop you are changing all the values ​​again, this is inefficient, also its value may be integer and not of type `string`, try with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
df['col1'] = np.where(df['col1'].eq(1), 'A', 'BC')
print(df)
```

If you want keep other values of col1:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace({1: 'A', 2: 'BC'})
```